# Can $parse or $eval be used to evaluate a stingified boolean equation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, eval

I'm trying to understand $parse and $eval better and figure out if they are (or can be) used in a manner that I thought possible. I've created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fqs5n7tHj9XDxpcdeBA8?p=preview) to show my issue/question and reference their lines

I have an object with a boolean expression as a string value, which will be served to me from an external source (script.js line 6-10):

```
$scope.input123456abcdefg;

$scope.object123456abcdefg = {
  disabled: "input123456abcdefg == 'hello'"
};
```

I have tried a few code walkthroughs, all of which have basically boiled down to (my understanding) of these 2 types of operations/functions (script.js line 12-15):

```
var template_v1 = $parse('object123456abcdefg.disabled');
$scope.expression_v1 = template_v1($scope);

$scope.expression_v2 = $scope.$eval('object123456abcdefg.disabled');
```

What I'm expecting (hoping) for either $parse or $eval to do is create an equivalent to (script.js line 17):

```
$scope.expression_v3 = $scope.input123456abcdefg == 'hello';
```

However, I'm only returned the same string as when I started, which you can see evaluated on the DOM (index.html lines 24 & 28).

Can $parse or $eval be used in this fashion, and if so where am I dropping the ball at? Or is there another option in Angular that is correct for performing this type of action?

Comment: im 99% sure you can simply use array syntax and forget about eval()

Comment: Don't. Just because you can does not mean you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @dandavis I'd avoid eval() altogether if possible.[Here a small explanation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)

Why do you require the value of object123456abcdefg.disabled to be passed in?

EDIT: If you really could not find another way of doing so, this is how you make your code work:

```
$scope.expression_v2 = $scope.$eval($scope.object123456abcdefg.disabled);
```

Comment: I was asked to find if there would be a good (proper) way to resolve this, and I'm glad that I couldn't find anything and checked with more knowledgable programmers than myself. I'm going to recommend the method of how this data is passed be changed.

Regardless, thank you for your time and suggestion